# Dates shown as NAN for dropdown items but for the cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code returning NAN/NAN/NAN in the drop down menu for some reason. Not sure what's causing it. ***The code in the code snippet of Stackoverflow isn't functional for some reason*** but I have the same code in the [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/69ykxfmd/1/) which will show what I am trying to explain. The way it should display is as follows:

1) Since `A` has two dates associated with it, the cell should show the first date (which it's showing fine) and then the second date in the dropdown which is `1481198400000`.

2)Similarly, `B` should show `1497348000000` and `1487764800000` in the dropdown menu.

But as shown in the JSFiddle, I am getting it like this (screenshot below):

[image]

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'A',
  date: '1481198400000'
}, {
  name: 'A',
  date: '1481198400000'
}, {
  name: 'B',
  date: '1552557600000'
}, {
  name: 'B',
  date: '1497348000000'
}, {
  name: 'B',
  date: '1487764800000'
}, {
  name: 'C',
  date: '1491818400000'
}, {
  name: 'D',
  date: '1491818400000'
}, {
  name: 'E',
  date: '1552384800000'
}];

var cl = function(s) {
  console.log(s);
}

var isUsedKey = function(arrayOfObject, key) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObject.length; i += 1) {
    if (arrayOfObject[i].key == key) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
};

var array = [];
var object = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (i == 0) {
    var newItem = {};
    newItem.key = data[i].name;
    newItem.dates = [data[i].date];
    array.push(newItem);
  } else {
    var item = data[i];
    var itemName = item.name;
    var itemDate = item.date;

    if (isUsedKey(array, itemName)) {
      for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[j].key == itemName) {
          var index = array[j].dates.length;
          array[j].dates[index] = itemDate;
        }
      }
    } else {
      var nextNewItem = {};
      nextNewItem.key = itemName;
      nextNewItem.dates = [itemDate];
      array.push(nextNewItem);
    }
  }
}

var newSource = {
  localdata: array,
  datafields: [{
    name: 'name',
    type: 'string',
    map: 'key'
  }, {
    name: 'date',
    type: 'date',
    map: 'dates>0',
    // format: 'dd.MM.yyyy'
    format: 'MM/dd/yyyy'
  }],
  datatype: "array"
};
var newAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(newSource);
console.log(newAdapter);

// Adding for dropdown icon

var iconrenderer = function(row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {
  return '<span style="position: relative; width: 100%; margin: 4px; float: ' + columnproperties.cellsalign + ';">' + newAdapter.formatDate(value, 'd') + '<img src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/images/icon-down.png" style="position: absolute; right: 5px;" /></span>';
}

$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
  source: newAdapter,
  editable: true,
  columns: [{
    text: 'Name',
    datafield: 'name',
    editable: false,
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  }, {
    text: 'Date',
    datafield: 'date',
    cellsformat: 'd',
    columntype: 'combobox',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    cellsrenderer: iconrenderer,
    createeditor: function(row, column, editor) {
      var info = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
      var groupName = info.name;
      var dates = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].key == groupName) {
          dates = array[i].dates;
        }
      }

      editor.jqxComboBox({
        autoDropDownHeight: true,
        source: dates,
        promptText: "Please Choose:"
      });
    },
    initeditor: function(row, column, editor) {
      var info = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
      var groupName = info.name;
      var dates = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].key == groupName) {
          dates = array[i].dates;
        }
      }

      editor.jqxComboBox({
        autoDropDownHeight: true,
        source: dates,
        promptText: "Previous Dates:",
        renderer: function(index_, label_, value_) {
          var formattedDate = "";
          //if (!isEmpty(value_)) {
          var dateObject = new Date(value_);
          formattedDate = (dateObject.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dateObject.getDate() + "/" + dateObject.getFullYear();
          //}
          return formattedDate;
        },
        renderSelectedItem: function(index, item) {
          var records = editor.jqxComboBox('getItems');
          var currentRecord = records[index].label;
          var formattedDate = "";
          //if (!isEmpty(value_)) {
          var dateObject = new Date(currentRecord);
          formattedDate = (dateObject.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dateObject.getDate() + "/" + dateObject.getFullYear();
          //}
          return formattedDate;
        }
      });
    },
    cellvaluechanging: function(row, column, columntype, oldvalue, newvalue) {
      // return the old value, if the new value is empty.
      if (newvalue == "") return oldvalue;
    },

  }],
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/generatedata.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
<link href="https://www.jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.arctic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://www.jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='jqxWidget'>
  <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you provide `value_` to the `Date()` constructor as a string when, to be interpreted as an epoch timestamp, the value needs to be an integer. As such you can use `parseInt()`:

```
var dateObject = new Date(parseInt(value_, 10));
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/v85qgxhy/)

Comment: Thanks @Rory McCrossan. I was trying to achieve the same using moment.js and it keeps on throwing `Invalid Date` in the dropdown. Here's the JSFiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/w9mjbth3/1/    Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Same problem. When using epoch timestamps MomentJS expect you to provide them to the constructor as ints, not strings, see the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/). Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1cmt4ya6/